# ClearCase transfers mastership of all objects in a directory?

Tags: clearcase

I know that we can transfer mastership of an object like this example:

At replica sanfran_hub, transfer mastership of element list.c to the sydney
replica.

```
multitool chmaster sydney list.c@@/main
Changed mastership of ″list.c″ to ″sydney″
```

However, I do not know how to transfer mastership of all files in a directory. Example:

```
sydney/
 sydney list1.c
 sydney list2.c
 sydney list3.c
 ...
```

If I run

```
multitool chmaster sydney sydney@@/main
```

It only change mastership of the directory "sydney", not all the files inside it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe there is a recursive option for [`chmaster`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_chmaster.htm).

That means you need to link this command to the result of a [`cleartool find` query](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_find.htm).

(Windows syntax)

```
 cleartool find sydney -exec "multitool chmaster sydney \"%CLEARCASE_PN%@@/main\""
```

(Unix syntax)

```
 cleartool find sydney -exec 'multitool chmaster sydney "$CLEARCASE_PN@@/main"'
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Addition, is there any way that we can get the string after the @@ . Instead of run cleartool find . -exec 'multitool chmaster sydney "$CLEARCASE_PN@@/main"' Could we use variable for @@/main

Comment: @MrFly911 yes, you can. `$CLEARCASE_PN` is itself a variable. If you set `main` to any other variable '`var`', you can use said variable '`var`' in the exec directive: `cleartool find sydney -exec 'multitool chmaster sydney "$CLEARCASE_PN@@/$var"'`

Comment: I have some problem with branch path, like list1.c@@/main/dev2 and list2.c@@/main/dev1/dev2 they are not same branch path. I want to get the branch path by variable, not hardcore like @@/main . Is there ny variable like $CLEARCASE_BRANCH_PATH? Example cleartool find sydney -exec 'multitool chmaster sydney "$CLEARCASE_PN@@$CLEARCASE_BRANCH_PATH"'

Comment: @MrFly911 not in one command. You can describe `$CLEARCASE_XPN` (`XPN`, not`PN`) in order to display the branch (see fmt_ccase: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm). And then, in a second path, use that information to `multitool chmaster` with the right branch.

Comment: @MrFly911 But if you are using bash, you can try and see some string manipulation (http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) can help: `${CLEARCASE_XPN%/*}` would remove the last `/xx`, transforming a `list2.c@@/main/dev1/dev2/3` into `list2.c@@/main/dev1/dev2`

Comment: Thank you very much! I am a ClearCase newbie. So that it is hard to do as your advice, but I will try :)

Comment: @MrFly911 sure, but are you on Windows or Unix? If Unix, which shell are you using?

Comment: I use Unix with bash shell

Comment: @MrFly911 in that case, one command *might* be enough, `cleartool find sydney -exec 'multitool chmaster sydney "${CLEARCASE_XPN%/*}"'`

Comment: @MrFly911 That is what I feared: `CLEARCASE_XPN` isn't really a bash variable. You need two passes then. One to generate the right String, one to `multitool chmaster`.